# from set of parameters is there any way that after plotting remove parameters and attach new parameters dynamically in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Actually i want to know that **how to dynamically update the graph in matplotlib** ,for my case the number of **parameters are 10 in number** and after selecting certain parameters and getting a plot i want to change the set of parameters and **without again plotting want to change in the graph dynamically** in the **run time** is there any way? please suggest

```
m=['H','.','<','^','*','+','x','@']
    cnt=0
    for i in all:# here all has the row wise data to plot 
       matplotlib.pyplot.plot(l3,i,m[cnt])# l3 contains the values about the x axis
        cnt=cnt+1
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.legend(para,loc='best')# para contains the info about the y parameters

    plt.show()
```

this is the result I got suppose I want to remove D from this graph dynaically and add E then how to do it i don't have any knowledge regarding this 
[Here is the result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwtEB.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Like you can add the code you did , what output you got and what do you expect. It gives more clarity and insights for the contributors to answer. :)

Comment: I explained sir

Comment: I have uploaded please see it